# Comparing lists in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I want to compare two lists in Mathematica, see what elements in the first list are not in, the second list, and then print out the non-equal elements. I generated two lists and I want to use a for loop to go through the two lists and compare each element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
list1 = {3, 56, 9, 8, 7, 33, 5};
list2 = {33, 4, 56, 7, 9, 23};
```

The usual idiom would be `Complement`.  Note, it sorts the output.

```
notinlist2 = Complement[list1, list2]
notinlist1 = Complement[list2, list1]
```

> ```
> {3, 5, 8}
> {4, 23}
> ```

Using a `For` loop preserves the order from `list1`

```
notinlist2 = {};

For[i = 1, i <= Length[list1], i++,
 If[FreeQ[list2, list1[[i]]],
  AppendTo[notinlist2, list1[[i]]]]]

notinlist2
```

> ```
> {3, 8, 5}
> ```

The same can be achieved with `DeleteDuplicates`

```
Drop[DeleteDuplicates[Join[list2, list1]], Length[list2]]
```

> ```
> {3, 8, 5}
> ```

Comment: Does this work for a list of matrices?

Comment: From the [docs](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Complement.html) : `Complement[Tuples[{0, 1}, 3], Partition[IntegerDigits[12345, 2], 3, 1]]`.  This gives the complement of an 8 x 3 and a 12 x 3 matrix, returning rows found in the former which are not in the latter.